# PHP _REQUEST[variable] different in two servers

Tags: php, string, post, encoding

I have an issue with post data encoding.
I'm sending (from my application) data (in UTF8) to the php scrypt and the same data:
1) in local server looks like:

```
_REQUEST["data"]    {"type": "FeatureCollection"
```

2) in remote (commercial) server looks like

```
_REQUEST["data"]    %7B%22type%22:%20%22FeatureCollection%22
```

Is a setting parameter in PHP or function to bring chars from hexadecimal forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use URL Decoding.

```
$data = urldecode($_REQUEST["data"]);
```

You can use the UTF-8 decode function along with urldecode,

```
$data = utf8_decode(urldecode($_REQUEST["data"]));
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for the rapid answer.